# Showing alert message on the same jsp page

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I have a jsp page , when on click of a button takes me to a servlet . In that servlet I basically check for a condition, if its sucess I will rediret to a new page which is working good. But when there is an error, I would like to show an error message on the same page without reloading/redirect to the same page.

Below is my servlet code snippet that I tried but it doesn't seem to work,

```
            if(error){
        if (!response.isCommitted())
            {
                response.reset();
                response.resetBuffer();
            }
            response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_NO_CONTENT);
            response.setContentType("text/html"); 
            PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(response.getOutputStream()); 
            pw.write("<html><body><script>alert('Error')</script></body></html>");
            pw.close(); 
            response.getOutputStream().flush();
            response.getOutputStream().close();
            response.flushBuffer();
        return;
        }
```

I am even setting the **SC_no_content** status to avoiding haveing reload the page or somthing, but the alert msg doesn't come up what so ever.. Please suggest.

Comment: If it _takes me to a servlet_ the request is already sent, so it is too late show the alert on the previous page.

Comment: This servlet has nothing to do in this scenario.Paste your JSP page in which you are submitting your form to this servlet.On that JSP you can show that alert using JS

Comment: 1) You **should not** reset the response content. 2) You **should not** write HTML content directly from the servlet, instead navigate to the desired JSP. In this case, you can do a forward to the same view or use an ajax call to execute your servlet, and according to the results you will show the error message or fire your navigation.

Comment: @freak looks like OP want to do the things right by validating the data in server side but he needs a hand about how to do this and display the error messages on the current view.

Answer (score 1):

You need to understand the flow of your application.

1. You click a button which sends an **HTTP request** to the server.
2. Your `Servlet` handles the request.

   - If it's valid, you send an **HTTP response** that redirects to another page (or maybe you do a forward that's sends an HTTP response that contains the HTML generated by a jsp).
   - If it's not valid, you send an **HTTP response** that contains:

   `<html><body><script>alert('Error')</script></body></html>`

If you're (correctly) doing the validation on your server, you can send that request asynchronously with javascript and, based on the result, take action.

Comment: Yep, thats right. But i need this to be alerted on the same page which doesn't happen. One more thing is, am not using a button here. rather I have an anchor tag. [also tried _self and_top]  
<a href="'+URL1+'" target="_blank" title="test">Test</a>

Comment: @Faz That's what I said, if you want to validate on the server, you need to send an ajax request and update your current DOM.

Comment: Okie, am trying the ajax piece now.

Comment: Yep, the responsetext is showing up fine, but for some reasons the page is reloaded. Any insight?

Comment: @Faz Please edit your question with new details of what you are doing.

Answer (score 0):

if you use a servlet to validate your data you need to reload the page.

anyway there is a workaround
post your form to a blank target through an ajax request, parse the result and if is in error show the message through javascript, it there is no error perform a refirect through a javascript

try to check this [jquery plugin](http://sourceforge.net/projects/iframepostform/?source=dlp)

another way is to use [cometD](http://cometd.org/), so that you can send response from server code to javascript code without do a post on your client